# Where to put services library in laravel Domain Driven Design (DDD)

Tags: laravel, domain-driven-design

`DDD` is a shorthand for `Domain Driven Design`

**Question 1:**

Previously, when using original Laravel pattern..
To use service library such as FileOperation, Curl, Calling process such as 'ps, python script' & etc..
The file default to be placed on `app/Services` directory..

**Question 2:**

I also has custom stub generator. That generate stub using command such as php artisan make:anything.
Since research some [articles](https://www.hibit.dev/posts/43/domain-driven-design-with-laravel-9) and finding that the `app/Console/Kernel.php` was moved to `app/Infrastructure/Laravel/Kernel/Console.php`

Upon using DDD. I don't know where to put these file.
Googling for a few day, and only found bunch of non-DDD related

Where should I put the services as Question 1 explains?
It better to be put on:

- `app/Infrastructure/Service`
- `app/Infrastructure/<service name dir>/*.php`
- `app/Application`

Or let it stay on `app/Services`

And where those console generator to be put?
Should it stay on `app/Console/*.php`
Or placing on:

- `app/Interface/Console/*.php`
- `app/Infrastructure/Console/*.php`

Or any suggestion

Comment: Question 1 is not a question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article you are quoting confuses DDD with 4-tier architecture.

##### Domain driven development

DDD is a concept forged by Eric Evans in his book published in 2003 [Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software](https://a.co/d/4navJGA). The principle of DDD is to create a separate unit of code, called *domain layer*, which contains all code needed for business rules validation. This unit of code must be designed to work across multiple applications and should be independent of infrastructure.

DDD can be used in different application architectures: although the unit of code is called *business layer* you may use DDD in non-layered architecture application. As much as DDD states that infrastructure-dependent concepts do not go in the domain layer, it has no claim on how non-domain units are structured.

As far as DDD itself is concerned, FileOperation, Curl, ... go "outside of the domain layer".

##### 4-tier architecture

4-tier architecture is a classical n-tier architecture formed with 4 independent layers:

- User interface / presentation layer
- Domain / business layer
- Infrastructure / persistence / data layer
- Application layer

There are subtilities on which layer is able to reference what layer, but doing 4-tier with DDD usually means that the domain layer is not allowed to reference code from other layers. This was a change from previous practices of n-tier where a business layer would reference a data layer. This made the business rules unit of code infrastructure-dependant, thus not transferrable to other applications. Changing that practice was the main purpose of DDD.

Traditionally, a n-tier architecture has a single monolithic infrastructure layer. Oftentimes infrastructure was limited to a single RDBMS and you would implement object-to-sql operations in the infrastructure layer, acting as a mediator between your domain model and the database. Some applications had more complex infrastructure with multiple sources of data, and some engineers started to promote less linear architecture patterns, such as [Hexagonal architecture by Alistair Cockburn in 2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_architecture_(software)), which was later enriched as Onion architecture by Jeffrey Palermo in 2008, then Clean architecture proposed by Robert C. Martin in 2012.

##### Conclusion

I would treat h1b1t's structure as a mere suggestion, I don't have enough expertise to critique how they suggest to organize the `app/Infrastructure/Laravel` folder. However my understanding is that this folder contains all infrastructure-dependent code *from* the framework. So code such as your services should not go there.

If your services are used when accessing your infrastructure (database, external apis, ...), it should go in the `app/Infrastructure` directory but outside `app/Infrastructure/Laravel`. How you structure your infrastructure layer depends on your actual infrastructure and should have one directory per external service. If this code is used when calling different sources of data, then you can have some `app/Infrastructure/Commons` directory.

If these services are infrastructure independent, they go in the `app/Application`. The console generator, for instance, is not infrastructure-dependant and should go in `app/Application/Console`

Comment: Thank you for details explanation..
Upon the ideology that you provide, I came across to this articles https://matthiasnoback.nl/2020/02/is-all-code-in-vendor-infrastructure-code/ that explains to me about `I would treat h1b1t's structure as a mere suggestion`.. And I also realize that,, what is this spaghetti code that I've been writing.. :)

Comment: And I want to ask some additional question regarding of it.. Could you provide some basic github project that reflect the good practice, best structural design on how DDD is write (PHP is preferred). I see a few but most of them is different from each other that make me wonder what is the correct way. And referring to this, https://matthiasnoback.nl/2017/08/layers-ports-and-adapters-part-2-layers/ I know how the good structure is structured.. But how to write it??.. I have no idea.. Perhaps some good example of basic github project may help for reference.. Thank you

Comment: I think you should consider why you want to do DDD at all first. DDD was born in OOP compiled languages, because there was a concern with binaries references in these languages. PHP do not face such challenge because it is both functional, interpreted, and file based. PHP devs looked into DDD because that was how others languages addressed the problem, but I don't think that was a smart move. I would rather look into client/api and vertical slice architecture. Writing a domain layer can make sense in specific cases but requires a lot of work to do properly.

Comment: I accept the answer.. After a few research followed by the suggestion.. DDD is not what I'm looking for,, but as the title said for DDD... I solve the problem using vertical slice architecture, a bit more like upgraded version of DDD.. Seem nice & clean since it can reduce the dependency injector need for each file using feature.. And I able to use, merge the method that I struggle to solve.. Thank you for suggesting vertical slide architecture.. For future reader who need to know, could read https://www.jimmybogard.com/vertical-slice-architecture/ for basic understanding.. Cheer ^_^